# Rejected edit results in loss of constructive code modification

Tags: discussion

I rejected this [suggested edit](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/22215) from an anonymous user, as it clearly conflicted with the original post. The odd thing was though, the edit actually seemed to be rather constructive, as it modified the code (not in an insignificant way), and I was hoping that the suggested edit might be posted as an answer but after having just taken another look at the question I can see that it has not.

Should I post this code modification as an answer myself? By the time that you get around to reading this question, I may have already done so, as it *does* seem a shame to lost some constructive effort, that was made by someone.

Also, who are these anonymous users? Doesn't anyone who makes an edit actually have to log on to the site? If not, then that seems rather dangerous and foolhardy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I post this code modification as an answer myself?

It seems odd for someone to "answer" a question by editing the question instead of posting an answer.

If you think the edit helps you might make an answer yourself, attributing it to some anonymous editor.

> Also, who are these anonymous users?

That's another odd thing. Perhaps the fact that the question was migrated from another part of SE explains that bit.

Comment: Cheers, I've posted the [answer](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33553/arduino-time-between-interrupts-in-pov-led-display#answer-33584).

Comment: It has happened again, with the same post, very strange. Someone clearly is trying to (possibly legitimately) edit the question. See  [here](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/22263). I have rejected it again, to be on the safe side. If it is the OP, they should just create an account.

Comment: It looks like it is the OP - Herioz - (who has an account anyway).

Comment: Ok, thanks for looking the account up.  Well I've left a comment on the question. However, it is odd that, as they have an account that it still comes through as anon user... Unless they aren't bothering to log in with it, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can always post it as a community wiki. That way you are not taking the credit for the work of someone else.

Comment: Good point. I need to revisit that question, it does seem that it *was* the OP making those edits after all.